# Capistrano gives DNS spoofing warning even though I can SSH just fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, capistrano

I have a Rails app that I'm trying to deploy with Capistrano (which I've never used before today). When I run `cap deploy`, I get a DNS spoofing warning. I've pasted the output [here](http://pastebin.com/dP1Y6jnv).

Even if I delete `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, I still get the spoofing warning. Also, I can SSH into my server just fine, without any spoofing warning. (I have RSA keys set up.)

Any idea why this could be happening? Here is my `config/deploy.rb`:

```
require "bundler/capistrano"

set :user, "jason"
set :domain, "sniphq.com"
set :application, "Snip"
set :repository,  "ssh://jason@sniphq.com/var/git/snip.git"

set :scm, "git"
set :branch, "master"
set :git_shallow_clone, true
set :scm_verbose, true

role :web, domain                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, domain                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  domain, :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run

set :deploy_to, "/home/jason/snip-cap"
set :deploy_via, :export

# if you're still using the script/reaper helper you will need
# these http://github.com/rails/irs_process_scripts

# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server *sniphq.com* is trying to access itself when cloning your repo from

`ssh://jason@sniphq.com/var/git/snip.git`.

This may cause the warning as well if the known_hosts contain a different ip for that name.

Try deleting `/home/jason/.ssh/known_hosts` on the server as well or simply remove line 3 there.

Comment: Also, I ended up changing it from `ssh://jason@sniphq.com/var/git/snip.git` to just `/var/git/snip.git`. It feels kind of weird to have a server SSH into itself.

Comment: Thats just fine. Didn't know if you are deploying to another server as well. Then it would make sense.